# Output IP address and exec command after counting occurrences of string using bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

I have the following sample data from the log file:

```
[10:35:52] world_log_data: user (starrr)(NormieBL)@Arca is already connected on srv 21
[10:35:53] world_log_data: user (starrr)(NormieBL)@Arca is already connected on srv 21
[10:35:54] world_log_data: user (starrr)(NormieBL)@Arca is already connected on srv 21
[10:35:54] world_log_data: user (starrr)(NormieBL)@Arca is already connected on srv 21
[10:35:54] world_log_data: user (starrr)(NormieBL)@Arca is already connected on srv 21
[10:35:56] world_log_event: kick (starrr)(NormieBL)@Arca from srv 192.168.1.6(21)  
[10:39:17] world_log_data: user (chrisxJ02)(Delaon)@Arca is already connected on srv 7
[10:39:19] world_log_data: user (chrisxJ02)(Delaon)@Arca is already connected on srv 7
[10:39:23] world_log_event: kick (chrisxJ02)(Delaon)@Arca from srv 192.168.1.39(7)
[10:39:17] world_log_data: user (test01)(testDW)@Arca is already connected on srv 39
[10:39:19] world_log_data: user (test01)(testDW)@Arca is already connected on srv 39
[10:39:23] world_log_event: kick (test01)(testDW)@Arca from srv 192.168.1.100(39)
```

I need to count the number of occurrences of a string using bash and execute a command once the string repeats itself more than 5 times.

- the string to search for in the log file is `is already connected on srv`
- the number that follows the string (eg, `21`) can change after the process is restarted, so the complete string will be something like this `is already connected on srv #` where `#` is the `ID number` of a PC and can randomly be anywhere from `1 to 100`
- a given number cannot have more than one IP address assigned (eg, `21` can only have `IP_A(21)` and it cannot have `IP_A(21)` and `IP_B(21)`
- the IP address can change after process restart, so the log file may register a different IP address for number `21` next time it restarts (eg, `192.168.1.6(21)` can become `192.168.0.72(21)`
- the code `awk` or `grep` I guess would the best should find the lines containing the `string + number` and count them; if more than 5 occurrences are the same it should execute the command
- if multiple entries show up 5+ times the code should flag all of them, however, this shouldn't be necessary as I plan to truncate the `.log` file right after detection
- the point of interest is parsing the IP address after the script detects multiple occurences of the mentioned string and then `telnet` into that IP address.
- both the `IP address` and the `ID number` associated with it will change so two variables will be needed, the only static string the script should look for is `is already connected on srv` and followed by the `ID number`

Some examples of how the script should behave:

```
if string "is already connected on srv 21" count is =>5 times then "exec command telnet 192.168.1.6"
if string "is already connected on srv 7" count is =>5 times then "exec command telnet 192.168.1.39"
```

Here is an attempt using `awk` but the IP address is not correctly displayed under the regular format containing dots such as 127.0.0.1. Probably `grep` would be a better choice.

```
#!/bin/bash

search_string='is already connected on srv'
threshold=5


awk -v ss="${search_string}" -v threshold="${threshold}" '

$0 ~ ss    { counter[$NF]++ }                    # counter[##]++

/ IPaddr_/ { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)               # loop through fields ...
                 if ($(i) ~ "IPaddr_") {         # looking for string "IPaddr_"
                    split($(i),arr,"[()]")       # split "IPaddr_?(##)" on parents
                    ip[arr[2]]=arr[1]            # ip[##]=IPaddr_?
                    next}                        # skip to next input line
           }

END        { for (i in counter)                  # for every "##" encountered ...
                 if (counter[i] >= threshold)    # if the count is greater than threshold then ...
                    print i,ip[i]                # print "## IPaddr_?"
           }
' world.log
```

Comment: Can you boil this down to a narrow, specific question? A lot of this context is more things _about your script_ than about a technical problem you encountered while writing your script. Ideally, the question should be all about the problem itself, with the code provided as a [mre] -- the _shortest possible thing_ that lets someone else reproduce for and test fixes to the problem that caused the question to be asked. (That is: Don't ask for help with your script; ask for help with a problem you encountered while writing your script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- we only have to deal with IPv4 formats
- the only strings like `<space><IPv4-address>(` in the file are the ones we're interested in

One idea is to modify the current `awk` code to look for `<space><IPv4-address>(`:

```
awk -v ss="${search_string}" -v threshold="${threshold}" '

$0 ~ ss    { counter[$NF]++ }

/ [0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+[(]/ {

             for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
                 if ( $(i) ~ "[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+[(]" ) {
                    split($(i),arr,"[()]")
                    ip[arr[2]]=arr[1]
                    next}
           }

END        { for (i in counter)
                 if (counter[i] >= threshold)
                    print i,ip[i]
           }
' world.log
```

Run against the sample input with `threshold=5` generates:

```
21 192.168.1.6
```

With `threshold=2` this generates:

```
7 192.168.1.39
21 192.168.1.6
39 192.168.1.100
```

---

At this point OP can manipulate the `awk` output as appropriate (eg, load into array(s), load each row into `while` loop variables, etc).

For `while` loop processing it will be a bit cleaner if we move the `awk` code into a function, eg:

```
parse_srv_ip ()
{
    awk -v ss="${search_string}" -v threshold="${threshold}" '
    ... snip ...
    ' "$1"              # name of log file passed as only arg to function
}
```

We can then process the `awk` output via a `while` loop like such:

```
logfile='world.log'

while read -r srv ip
do
    echo "srv = $srv : ip = $ip"
done < <(parse_srv_ip "${logfile}")
```

This generates:

```
srv = 7 : ip = 192.168.1.39
srv = 21 : ip = 192.168.1.6
srv = 39 : ip = 192.168.1.100
```

**NOTE:** OP would obviously replace the `echo "srv ..."` with the desired code (eg, `"exec command telnet..."`, etc).

Comment: Amazing, just tested and after several small changes works as intended. I wanted to ask if `unset ` is necessary in this case and how would a `if` condition would look like and is there any benefit of using `while` over `if` here? I will set a cronjob to run the script every hour or so anyway.

Comment: the `unset -f` is just a habit I got into a long time ago for ... some reason ...; as for `if` vs `while` ... depends on what logic you're looking to implement and how you plan on capturing/using the `awk` output (keep in mind how you'd run your `if` if `awk` returns more than one line/set of data)